# WiFi-Button of Packard Bell easynote TK8 not working anymore

Tags: wireless

What's gone wrong with my WIFI?

> Packard Bell easynote TK85 Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

I have a button that turns WiFi on/off.
I use it often to save battery power. This time however it did not turn WiFi back on. 
Please help me to get it working again.

The resuts of:

> sudo lshw -class network

```
alias symbol:vxlan_get_rx_port vxlan
alias symbol:w1_add_master_device wire
alias symbol:w1_calc_crc8 wire
alias symbol:w1_ds2760_read w1_ds2760
alias symbol:w1_ds2760_recall_eeprom w1_ds2760
alias symbol:w1_ds2760_store_eeprom w1_ds2760
alias symbol:w1_ds2760_write w1_ds2760
alias symbol:w1_ds2780_eeprom_cmd w1_ds2780
alias symbol:w1_ds2780_io w1_ds2780
alias symbol:w1_ds2781_eeprom_cmd w1_ds2781
alias symbol:w1_ds2781_io w1_ds2781
alias symbol:w1_next_pullup wire
alias symbol:w1_read_8 wire
alias symbol:w1_read_block wire
alias symbol:w1_register_family wire
alias symbol:w1_remove_master_device wire
alias symbol:w1_reset_bus wire
alias symbol:w1_reset_resume_command wire
alias symbol:w1_reset_select_slave wire
alias symbol:w1_touch_block wire
alias symbol:w1_unregister_family wire
alias symbol:w1_write_8 wire
alias symbol:w1_write_block wire
alias symbol:wa_create wusb_wa
alias symbol:wa_dti_start wusb_wa
alias symbol:wa_process_errored_transfers_run wusb_wa
alias symbol:wa_urb_dequeue wusb_wa
alias symbol:wa_urb_enqueue wusb_wa
alias symbol:wa_urb_enqueue_run wusb_wa
alias symbol:wdev_to_ieee80211_vif mac80211
alias symbol:whci_wait_for whci
alias symbol:wimax_dev_add wimax
alias symbol:wimax_dev_init wimax
alias symbol:wimax_dev_rm wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg_alloc wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg_data wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg_data_len wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg_len wimax
alias symbol:wimax_msg_send wimax
alias symbol:wimax_report_rfkill_hw wimax
alias symbol:wimax_report_rfkill_sw wimax
alias symbol:wimax_reset wimax
alias symbol:wimax_rfkill wimax
alias symbol:wimax_state_change wimax
alias symbol:wimax_state_get wimax
alias symbol:wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_free cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_new_nm cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_register cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_rfkill_set_hw_state cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_rfkill_start_polling cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_rfkill_stop_polling cfg80211
alias symbol:wiphy_to_ieee80211_hw mac80211
alias symbol:wiphy_unregister cfg80211
alias symbol:wl1251_alloc_hw wl1251
alias symbol:wl1251_free_hw wl1251
alias symbol:wl1251_init_ieee80211 wl1251
alias symbol:wl1271_acx_init_mem_config wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_acx_pm_config wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_acx_set_ht_capabilities wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_acx_sleep_auth wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_cmd_configure wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_cmd_data_path wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_cmd_send wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_cmd_test wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_debugfs_update_stats wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_format_buffer wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_free_tx_id wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_ps_elp_sleep wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_ps_elp_wakeup wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_tx_flush wlcore
alias symbol:wl1271_tx_min_rate_get wlcore
alias symbol:wl12xx_acx_mem_cfg wlcore
alias symbol:wl12xx_cmd_build_probe_req wlcore
alias symbol:wl12xx_debug_level wlcore
alias symbol:wl12xx_is_dummy_packet wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_alloc_hw wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_boot_run_firmware wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_boot_upload_firmware wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_boot_upload_nvs wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_calc_packet_alignment wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_cmd_generic_cfg wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_cmd_wait_for_event_or_timeout wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_disable_interrupts wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_disable_interrupts_nosync wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_enable_interrupts wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_ba_rx_constraint wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_beacon_loss wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_channel_switch wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_dummy_packet wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_inactive_sta wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_max_tx_failure wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_roc_complete wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_rssi_trigger wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_sched_scan_completed wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_event_soft_gemini_sense wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_free_hw wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_get_native_channel_type wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_probe wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_remove wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_scan_sched_scan_results wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_scan_sched_scan_ssid_list wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_set_key wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_set_partition wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_set_scan_chan_params wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_synchronize_interrupts wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_translate_addr wlcore
alias symbol:wlcore_tx_complete wlcore
alias symbol:wm1811_regmap_config wm8994_regmap
alias symbol:wm8350_dcdc25_set_mode wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8350_dcdc_set_slot wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8350_isink_set_flash wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8350_ldo_set_slot wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8350_register_led wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8350_register_regulator wm8350_regulator
alias symbol:wm8400_register_regulator wm8400_regulator
alias symbol:wm8804_pm snd_soc_wm8804
alias symbol:wm8804_probe snd_soc_wm8804
alias symbol:wm8804_regmap_config snd_soc_wm8804
alias symbol:wm8804_remove snd_soc_wm8804
alias symbol:wm8903_mic_detect snd_soc_wm8903
alias symbol:wm8958_regmap_config wm8994_regmap
alias symbol:wm8962_mic_detect snd_soc_wm8962
alias symbol:wm8994_base_regmap_config wm8994_regmap
alias symbol:wm8994_irq_exit wm8994_irq
alias symbol:wm8994_irq_init wm8994_irq
alias symbol:wm8994_regmap_config wm8994_regmap
alias symbol:wm9705_codec wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm9712_codec wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm9713_codec wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_config_gpio wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_get_gpio wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_read_aux_adc wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_reg_read wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_reg_write wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_register_mach_ops wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_set_gpio wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_set_suspend_mode wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wm97xx_unregister_mach_ops wm97xx_ts
alias symbol:wmi_evaluate_method wmi
alias symbol:wmi_get_event_data wmi
alias symbol:wmi_has_guid wmi
alias symbol:wmi_install_notify_handler wmi
alias symbol:wmi_query_block wmi
alias symbol:wmi_remove_notify_handler wmi
alias symbol:wmi_set_block wmi
alias symbol:wpan_phy_find ieee802154
alias symbol:wpan_phy_for_each ieee802154
alias symbol:wpan_phy_free ieee802154
alias symbol:wpan_phy_new ieee802154
alias symbol:wpan_phy_register ieee802154
alias symbol:wpan_phy_unregister ieee802154
alias symbol:write_bytes_to_xdr_buf sunrpc
alias symbol:write_dst dst
alias symbol:wusb_cluster_id_get wusbcore
alias symbol:wusb_cluster_id_put wusbcore
alias symbol:wusb_dev_destroy wusbcore
alias symbol:wusb_et_name wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbd wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_b_create wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_b_destroy wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_chid_set wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_create wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_destroy wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_giveback_urb wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_handle_dn wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_mmcie_rm wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_mmcie_set wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_reset_all wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_rh_control wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_rh_start_port_reset wusbcore
alias symbol:wusbhc_rh_status_data wusbcore
alias symbol:x86_emulate_instruction kvm
alias symbol:x86_set_memory_region kvm
alias symbol:xc2028_attach tuner_xc2028
alias symbol:xc4000_attach xc4000
alias symbol:xc5000_attach xc5000
alias symbol:xdr_buf_from_iov sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_buf_read_netobj sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_buf_subsegment sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_buf_trim sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_commit_encode sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_decode_array2 sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_decode_netobj sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_decode_string_inplace sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_decode_word sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_array2 sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_netobj sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_opaque sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_opaque_fixed sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_string sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_encode_word sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_enter_page sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_init_decode sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_init_decode_pages sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_init_encode sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_inline_decode sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_inline_pages sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_partial_copy_from_skb sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_process_buf sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_read_pages sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_reserve_space sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_restrict_buflen sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_set_scratch_buffer sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_shift_buf sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_skb_read_bits sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_stream_pos sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_terminate_string sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_truncate_encode sunrpc
alias symbol:xdr_write_pages sunrpc
alias symbol:xen_privcmd_fops xen_privcmd
alias symbol:xfrm4_tunnel_deregister tunnel4
alias symbol:xfrm4_tunnel_register tunnel4
alias symbol:xfrm6_tunnel_alloc_spi xfrm6_tunnel
alias symbol:xfrm6_tunnel_deregister tunnel6
alias symbol:xfrm6_tunnel_register tunnel6
alias symbol:xfrm6_tunnel_spi_lookup xfrm6_tunnel
alias symbol:xfrm_aalg_get_byid xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_aalg_get_byidx xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_aalg_get_byname xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_aead_get_byname xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_calg_get_byid xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_calg_get_byname xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_count_pfkey_auth_supported xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_count_pfkey_enc_supported xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_ealg_get_byid xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_ealg_get_byidx xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_ealg_get_byname xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xfrm_probe_algs xfrm_algo
alias symbol:xillybus_endpoint_discovery xillybus_core
alias symbol:xillybus_endpoint_remove xillybus_core
alias symbol:xillybus_init_endpoint xillybus_core
alias symbol:xillybus_isr xillybus_core
alias symbol:xor_blocks xor
alias symbol:xprt_adjust_cwnd sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_alloc sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_alloc_slot sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_complete_rqst sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_destroy_backchannel sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_disconnect_done sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_free sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_load_transport sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_lock_and_alloc_slot sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_lookup_rqst sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_register_transport sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_release_rqst_cong sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_release_xprt sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_release_xprt_cong sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_reserve_xprt sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_reserve_xprt_cong sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_set_retrans_timeout_def sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_set_retrans_timeout_rtt sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_setup_backchannel sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_unregister_transport sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_wait_for_buffer_space sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_wake_pending_tasks sunrpc
alias symbol:xprt_write_space sunrpc
alias symbol:xt_alloc_table_info x_tables
alias symbol:xt_check_entry_offsets x_tables
alias symbol:xt_check_match x_tables
alias symbol:xt_check_target x_tables
alias symbol:xt_copy_counters_from_user x_tables
alias symbol:xt_find_match x_tables
alias symbol:xt_find_revision x_tables
alias symbol:xt_find_table_lock x_tables
alias symbol:xt_find_target x_tables
alias symbol:xt_free_table_info x_tables
alias symbol:xt_hook_link x_tables
alias symbol:xt_hook_unlink x_tables
alias symbol:xt_proto_fini x_tables
alias symbol:xt_proto_init x_tables
alias symbol:xt_rateest_lookup xt_RATEEST
alias symbol:xt_rateest_put xt_RATEEST
alias symbol:xt_recseq x_tables
alias symbol:xt_register_match x_tables
alias symbol:xt_register_matches x_tables
alias symbol:xt_register_table x_tables
alias symbol:xt_register_target x_tables
alias symbol:xt_register_targets x_tables
alias symbol:xt_replace_table x_tables
alias symbol:xt_request_find_match x_tables
alias symbol:xt_request_find_target x_tables
alias symbol:xt_table_unlock x_tables
alias symbol:xt_tee_enabled x_tables
alias symbol:xt_unregister_match x_tables
alias symbol:xt_unregister_matches x_tables
alias symbol:xt_unregister_table x_tables
alias symbol:xt_unregister_target x_tables
alias symbol:xt_unregister_targets x_tables
alias symbol:xts_crypt xts
alias symbol:z8530_channel_load z85230
alias symbol:z8530_dead_port z85230
alias symbol:z8530_describe z85230
alias symbol:z8530_hdlc_kilostream z85230
alias symbol:z8530_hdlc_kilostream_85230 z85230
alias symbol:z8530_init z85230
alias symbol:z8530_interrupt z85230
alias symbol:z8530_nop z85230
alias symbol:z8530_null_rx z85230
alias symbol:z8530_queue_xmit z85230
alias symbol:z8530_shutdown z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_close z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_dma_close z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_dma_open z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_open z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_txdma_close z85230
alias symbol:z8530_sync_txdma_open z85230
alias symbol:zgid ib_core
alias symbol:zl10036_attach zl10036
alias symbol:zl10039_attach zl10039
alias symbol:zl10353_attach zl10353
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ lsmod | grep iwl
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ sudo modprobe iwl-3945
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwl-3945 not found.
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ ^C
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ sudo modprobe iwl-cfg80211
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwl-cfg80211 not found.
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ sudo modprobe -r iwl3945
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ sudo modprobe iwl3945
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-3.0-ia32:cxx-3.0-noarch:cxx-3.1-ia32:cxx-3.1-noarch:cxx-3.2-ia32:cxx-3.2-noarch:cxx-4.0-ia32:cxx-4.0-noarch:cxx-4.1-ia32:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-3.1-ia32:desktop-3.1-noarch:desktop-3.2-ia32:desktop-3.2-noarch:desktop-4.0-ia32:desktop-4.0-noarch:desktop-4.1-ia32:desktop-4.1-noarch:graphics-2.0-ia32:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.0-ia32:graphics-3.0-noarch:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.2-ia32:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-ia32:graphics-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.1-ia32:graphics-4.1-noarch:languages-3.2-ia32:languages-3.2-noarch:languages-4.0-ia32:languages-4.0-noarch:languages-4.1-ia32:languages-4.1-noarch:multimedia-3.2-ia32:multimedia-3.2-noarch:multimedia-4.0-ia32:multimedia-4.0-noarch:multimedia-4.1-ia32:multimedia-4.1-noarch:printing-3.2-ia32:printing-3.2-noarch:printing-4.0-ia32:printing-4.0-noarch:printing-4.1-ia32:printing-4.1-noarch:qt4-3.1-ia32:qt4-3.1-noarch:security-4.0-ia32:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-ia32:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

and the result of `lspci`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 01
       serial: b8:70:f4:ed:0f:ad
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=half firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:28 memory:b3400000-b340ffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2400000-b2403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@2:1.2
       logical name: eth1
       serial: f2:c1:f1:a3:7f:9e
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth ip=172.20.10.6 link=yes multicast=yes
onezeroone@10011100010000111101111101:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 05)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

and the result of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thats all I know so far.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo modprobe wl

modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.

Comment: I have used the script on the help section and this link is the result. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23564449/

Comment: I suggest that you install the correct driver for your wireless device. The procedure is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395

Comment: Thank you Chili555 you are a legend. Totally restore my trust in ubuntu and you guys that put in all the effort to help idiots like me.
It seems to be working after following that advice.
just need to use it for the suggested time to confirm.